# wordpress get_posts() overlapping printed records

Tags: wordpress

This is my very firs time to play around with wordpress. The theme I selected have a nice static look but that look disappears in dynamic mode. I followed some web tutorials to add my own function that fetches posts in one category and print in the position. I thought it was working fine until i noticed it is messing up the data. Here is my function first:

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 6,'orderby'=>'id','order'=>'desc' );

 $posts = get_posts($args);

  if(!empty($posts)){//yes we have posts

//loop results now
foreach($posts as $story) {
    setup_postdata( $story );
   the_ID();
  echo '<br/>'.the_title();
  echo '<br/>'.the_excerpt();
  }//end loop
 }//
```

The problem is the_ID and the_title() alaways take after the first record while the exceprt shows correct value of both records.

I did print array on posts variable and it holds two distinct ids and titles for the two records I have. But when I print, only the firs one is showing.

Someone suggested in some blog the correct way is :

```
$title = apply_filters('the_title', $story->title);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $story->content);
```

but then the title and content variables are null/blank.

Any idea what I am doing wrong please? I am newbie to wordpress so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved...avoid using get_posts() function and use WP_query() instead.